WSL - 'Command 'pip' not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt install python3-pip' after activating conda environment
I'm very new to WSL and Linux/bash as a whole - I'm actually only using it now out of curiosity. My aim is to activate a conda environment and then play a around a bit with some personal projects stored in my Windows desktop.
I've downloaded and installed miniconda and it seems to be working, at least partially, as intended as I'm able to activate an existing environment:
(path/to/env) <MyUserName>@<HostName>:~/windows-desktop/projects/example-project$

FYI ~/windows-desktop is a shortcut I added to quickly navigate to my windows desktop, /mnt/c/Users/MyUserName/Desktop.
However, after activating the conda environment, I wanted to check some of the python libraries installed with pip freeze and I got the error message Command 'pip' not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt install python3-pip. I get a similar error but for Python if I try to run something like python --version.
I'm not sure why I get that error since when I activate the environment via my Windows system  like Search for Conda Prompt -> cd path/to/env -> conda activate ./env -> pip freeze I am able to perform any of those actions since a pre-specified python version (and therefore pip) between others is installed in that environment.

Have you verified that the environment has python and pip installed? e.g., check conda list -p path/to/env? The sudo ... command should probably be avoided - it's suggesting to install stuff at the system level, whereas Conda environments should be independent of that and generally shouldn't require elevated privileges.

Also, if you're just toying, maybe consider pixi instead. It's still Conda-based, but far saner per-project management and real environment state modeling (better portability/reproducibility).

Did you install miniconda on windows and are then trying to use it from WSL, or did you install miniconda inside WSL?

@FlyingTeller I've installed it inside WSL but I also have it inside windows.

@merv Yes the environment does have python and pip installed (not posting the output because of limited length of a comment though). Also, I'll look up pixi, thanks!

FYI, when users ask for more info, it usually is a good idea to add that to the question body. Unlike reddit culture, it is strongly encouraged here to edit and improve the post. A good rule of thumb is: Fresh eyes coming in should never need to read comments to understand the issue. Also you can just do conda list '^(python|pip)$' to show only those versions (i.e., it takes a regex). Or show which python and which pip.
